# Add data attiribute values as an inline-css "width" value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, custom-data-attribute

I have code like this:

```
<span class="bar" data-percent="25,6"></span>
<span class="bar" data-percent="40,6"></span>
<span class="bar" data-percent="10,6"></span>
<span class="bar" data-percent="60"></span>
```

I want to take data-percent values, change comma to dot and add this value as a width to span.

Like this:

```
<span class="bar" data-percent="25,6" style="width: 25.6%"></span>
```

```js
$('span[class="bar"]').each(function(index, item) {
  var a = $(item).data('percent');
  a = a.replace(/,/g, '.') + '%';
  $(item).width(a);
});
```

```css
.bar {
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="bar" data-percent="25,6">First Span</span>
<span class="bar" data-percent="40,6">Second Span</span>
<span class="bar" data-percent="10,6">Third Span</span>
<span class="bar" data-percent="60">Fourth Span</span>
```

I write some jquery but it's not working, if there is no comma in data, jquery is not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/mod7910u/

Thanks to Josh, here is the last working and animated version:
https://jsfiddle.net/mg4p5bmc/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that the attribute `data-percent="60"` value is treated as a number. Whereas the other attribute values are treated as strings due to the fact that there is a comma present. Since the value 60 is a number, the `.replace()` method is throwing an error.

To resolve this, simply call the `.toString()` method before `.replace()` in order to ensure that the value is a string.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mg4p5bmc/)

```
var a = $(item).data('percent');
a = a.toString().replace(/,/g, '.') + '%';
```

You could also use the `String()` constructor to convert the value to a string as well:

```
var a = $(item).data('percent');
a = String(a).replace(/,/g, '.') + '%';
```